# Global Observable "is not defined on the instance but referenced during render"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, compiler-errors, global-variables

I have the following code in `main.js`:

```js
Vue.prototype.$globalData = Vue.observable({
  count: 0
});
```

I try to access such observable in a different component via

```html
<template>
  <div>
    {{ $globalData.counter }}
  </div>
</template>
```

but I get the following error:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "$globalData" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: [https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.%60)

There are no mentions of observables in the suggested link, so I'm somewhat lost at what the solution is supposed to be. As far as I can see others can run code fairly similar to mine (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62322428/9686427)).

---

Edit: I'm aware the message is technically a warning (`[Vue warn]`), but it's fairly significant as it prevents my component from loading.

Comment: make sure you define `Vue.prototype.$globalData` in main.js **before** you create the Vue instance `new Vue({...})`.  I believe your error usually comes from defining it after.  Also, your template code references `counter` when it should be `count`